# Can pypoetry install only the dependency that I ask it to add?

Tags: python, python-poetry

When running `poetry add package`, poetry decides to update some out of date dependencies without my asking:

```
$ poetry add -D ipython
Using version ^7.26.0 for ipython

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (6.8s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 13 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
  • Installing parso (0.8.2)
  • Installing ptyprocess (0.7.0)
  • Installing traitlets (5.0.5)
  • Installing wcwidth (0.2.5)
  • Installing appnope (0.1.2)
  • Installing backcall (0.2.0)
  • Updating connexion (2.8.0 -> 2.9.0) <---------- "I never asked for this"
  • Installing jedi (0.18.0)
  • Installing matplotlib-inline (0.1.2)
  • Installing pexpect (4.8.0)
  • Installing pickleshare (0.7.5)
  • Installing prompt-toolkit (3.0.19)
  • Installing ipython (7.26.0)
  • Updating ramda (0.6.0 -> 0.6.1) <---------- "I never asked for this"
```

And yet when getting the help for the command, there doesn't seem to be anything that suggest that it's possible to disable this behaviour:

```
$ poetry add --help
USAGE
  poetry add [-D] [-E <...>] [--optional] [--python <...>]
             [--platform <...>] [--source <...>] [--allow-prereleases]
             [--dry-run] [--lock] <name1> ... [<nameN>]

ARGUMENTS
  <name>                 The packages to add.

OPTIONS
  -D (--dev)             Add as a development dependency.
  -E (--extras)          Extras to activate for the dependency.
                         (multiple values allowed)
  --optional             Add as an optional dependency.
  --python               Python version for which the dependency must be
                         installed.
  --platform             Platforms for which the dependency must be
                         installed.
  --source               Name of the source to use to install the
                         package.
  --allow-prereleases    Accept prereleases.
  --dry-run              Output the operations but do not execute
                         anything (implicitly enables --verbose).
  --lock                 Do not perform operations (only update the
                         lockfile).

GLOBAL OPTIONS
  -h (--help)            Display this help message
  -q (--quiet)           Do not output any message
  -v (--verbose)         Increase the verbosity of messages: "-v" for
                         normal output, "-vv" for more verbose output and
                         "-vvv" for debug
  -V (--version)         Display this application version
  --ansi                 Force ANSI output
  --no-ansi              Disable ANSI output
  -n (--no-interaction)  Do not ask any interactive question

...
```

Any way to install only the package of interest?
I prefer not to update deps, even if the bump is a minor bump - dependabot exists for this purpose already.

Comment: If `ipython` 7.26.0 requires `connexion` 2.9.0 or above, then it's not going to work without upgrading.

Comment: OK, but then the question is: Does poetry add update only required updates for the root package that is being installed? Or does it update all minor bumps as well?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  `poetry` lets a package say exactly what range of versions it needs for each dependency.  It will install what the package needs.

Comment: What I am saying is that ipython does not have ramda as dependency; if I inspect my poetry.lock. ramda is a root node and is not mentioned as a dependency of any other package in the lockfile. Hence if my reading is correct, poetry also bumps dependencies on `poetry add`, even if the newly added dep doesn't need to get that updated package version.

Comment: Then one of the packages `ipython` needs must have required `ramda`.  It's a whole dependency tree.  `poetry` would not have made that up on its own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235707/discussion-between-philippe-hebert-and-tim-roberts).

Comment: I was not intending to be abrasive at all.  I do get the sense that you want to have your cake and eat it, too.  I'm just pointing out that it would not have upgraded `ramda` unless some module in the list asked for it.  You can try `poetry show --tree` to see what it thinks the dependencies are.

Comment: `poetry show --tree` in this case demonstrates that ramda is not a dep of anything but the project. So `poetry add` _does_ update deps even if unrelated to the new dep to add. I don't think that's intended. I'll open an issue on the repo.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TimRoberts `connexion` isn't possibly a `ipython` dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Add the dependency manually to `pyproject.toml` and then run `poetry lock --no-update` so that the dependency is added to your lock file without updating other packages according to their current version spec.

You could also lock all your version specs in your `pyproject.toml` to an exact version, i.e. use `0.8.2` instead `^0.8.2`.